# how to compile the curly braces inside string in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

This is my json data coming from back-end

```
menu:[{
  "menuUrl":"#/project/{{typeofproject}}/create"
}]


$scope.typeofproject="science"


$scope.url=menu[0].menuUrl;

<a ng-href="{{url}}"></a>
```

i got output like this #/project/{{typeofproject}}/create

instead i need #/project/science/create

Answer (score 2):

Try [$interpolate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24interpolate)

```
$scope.url = $interpolate(menu[0].menuUrl)({typeofproject: "science"})
```